# MySQL HAVING clause not working with ' ' nor " ", instead works without AS statement

Tags: mysql, sql, string, group-by, having-clause

```
SELECT 
    department_id, ROUND(MIN(salary), 2) AS 'Min Salary'
FROM
    employees
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING 'Min Salary' > 800;
```

This doesn't seem to work, but instead this:

```
SELECT 
    department_id, ROUND(MIN(salary), 2) AS min_salary
FROM
    employees
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING min_salary > 800
```

works just fine. Can someone give an answer to why i cant make
a HAVING clause with ' ' or " ", but instead i have to use the column name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `HAVING 'Min Salary' > 800`

The single quotes around the identifier turn it to a literal string. So this condition is actually checking if *string* `'Min Salary'` is greater than 800. When cast to a number, `'Min Salary'` becomes `0`, which is smaller than `800`. This is not what you expect.

Also, note that MySQL treats double quotes just like single quotes - whereas in some other databases like Oracle or Postgres, they are used to quote identifiers.

If you want to have a identifier that contains a space, then you need to use backticks, which is how MySQL quotes identifiers. So:

```
SELECT department_id, ROUND(MIN(salary), 2) AS `Min Salary`
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING `Min Salary` > 800;
```

Comment: Or you can `set sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES` and then use double-quotes as identifier delimiters.

Comment: or, better still, don't include spaces in table/column names